# I want to increase a value when some checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to increase the price if one or more check boxes are checked. Here is the code i have but it does not work

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="15" />Checkbox
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <span id="result"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var a=0;
 window.onload = function () {
 var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

 function check() {
    var a = a+value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result ' + a;
   }

 input.onchange = check;
 check();
   }
```

Comment: Try changing `var a = a+value;` to `a = a+value;`

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 1):

your variable "a" is in global scope when you have initialized it on the top var a = 0; If you want to use it, you can directly do a = a + 1.

When you declare it again as a var inside check function, it is now a new variable "a" bound to the check function scope as a new variable and its not referring to the variable declared at the top.

So the solution is remove declaration var and directly use it as a = a + 1 inside check function.

Also you need to check if checkbox is checked :

here is a working `fiddle` : https://jsfiddle.net/1m09z0cg/

Answer (score 1):

You've scoped your **a**  variable away in the check function, and you're calling the function **check** without the proper "this".

This should work

```
var a = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

  function check() {
    a = a + parseInt(this.value, 10);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result ' + a;
  }

  input.onchange = check;
  input.onchange(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong.

First, `querySelector` will only return the first element that matches the selector, if you want to get all checkboxes you'll have to use `querySelectorAll`.

Second, you're using `var a = a+value;` if you want to add `value` to the previous value of the global variable `a` you should use `a = a+value;`, by using `var a = ...` you're declaring a new variable `a` in the current context.

Third, there is no variable `value`, if you're trying to get the value of the clicked element use `event.currentTarget.value`.

```js
var checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']"));
var result = document.querySelector("#result");
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox){
    checkbox.onchange = function(){
        var total = checkboxes.reduce(function(a, c){
             return a + (c.checked ? parseInt(c.value):0);
        }, 0);
        result.textContent = "Result " + total;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="15" />Checkbox
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="15" />Checkbox 2
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="15" />Checkbox 3
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result">Result 0</span>
```